# how to filter register_taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, filter, addition

```
register_taxonomy( 'email_lists', array(
    'subscriber',
    'newsletter'
   ), array(
    'public' => false,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'update_count_callback' => array( &$this, 'update_post_term_count' ),
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_tagcloud' => false,
    'query_var' => true,
    'capabilities' => array(
     'manage_terms' => 'email_edit_lists',
     'edit_terms' => 'email_edit_lists',
     'delete_terms' => 'email_delete_lists',
     'assign_terms' => 'email_assign_lists',

    ),
   ) );
```

basing on what above is it possible to manage filter based on external attribute added on WP_terms ?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously this is quite an old question, but the [`register_taxonomy_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_taxonomy_args/) filter was introduced in WordPress 4.4 which allows any of the arguments to be filtered.

For example, if you wanted to make the taxonomy not public:

```
function so_22326532_register_taxonomy_args( $args, $taxonomy ) {

    if ( $taxonomy == 'email_lists' ) {

        $args['public'] = false;

    }

    return $args;

}

add_filter( 'register_taxonomy_args', 'so_22326532_register_taxonomy_args', 10, 2 );
```